# Group array items using object only unique values

Tags: jquery, json

My array is something like this:

```
var response = [
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_MINUTES",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 81
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_MINUTES",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 80
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_MINUTES",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 43
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 87
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 43
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_LD_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 84
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_MOVIE_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 54
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_MOVIE_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 58
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_MOVIE_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 75
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 13
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 54
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 45
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 43
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 88
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_BUYS_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 76
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 97
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 65
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 82
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 36
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 87
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PKG_REV_STD",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 54
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-01",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 92
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-02",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 65
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 99
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA_NEW",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 99
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA_NEW_1",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 99
  },
  {
    "PROCESS_TYPE": "MONTHLYCAR",
    "MODELNAME": "COX_PTB_DATA_NEW_1_11",
    "PROCESSDATE": "2019-04-03",
    "VARIABLENAME": "AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION": 99
  }
];
```

I want to convert this into:

```
responseData = [
  {
```

MODELNAME: "COX_PTB_DATA",  "VARIABLENAMEANDCONTRIBUTION":
                [
                    {
                        "VARIABLENAME":"AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
                        "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION":[23,54,66]

```
                },
                {
                    "VARIABLENAME":"AVG_12MO_PKG_REV_STD",
                    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION":[66,98,15]

                }
            ]
  },
  MODELNAME: "COX_PTB_DATA_NEW",  "VARIABLENAMEANDCONTRIBUTION":
            [
                {
                    "VARIABLENAME":"AVG_12MO_PPV_BUYS",
                    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION":[28,53,96]

                },
                {
                    "VARIABLENAME":"AVG_12MO_PKG_REV_STD",
                    "VARIABLECONTRIBUTION":[61,18,12]

                }
            ]
         }

]
```

I tried using .map,.rduce function using jquery but i cant able to form like this ,Below i have shared my fiddle[MY fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/L7tznhg0/32/)

Some one help me.

Comment: Please add relevant code here as a [mcve], as an [edit] to your question, not links to off-site resources.

Comment: I have added my fiddle